# Can Blender 2.80 run in windows 10 virtual machine

Tags: windows, osx

I have been doing a little research on virtual machines like VirtualBox and that got me wounding if I can run windows 10 on my mac using VirtualBox and run blender 2.80 on windows 10 and what do the extension pack do for you if you download it alongside the VirtualBox software?

My iMac system

am running an iMac osx late 2012 version 10.9.5 Macintosh HD with a 2.9 GHz Intel Core i5 Processor and 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 of Memory and an NVIDIA Geforce GTX Graphics card

Comment: Why don't you put Blender on your Mac?

Comment: because blender 2.80 won't work on my version of osx and am afraid of upgrading my iMac if something bad happens like all of my other software won't run anymore